# Не работает событие привязанное к элементу, созданному первым событием

Tags: jquery

Есть примерно такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("div").bind('click', function(event) {
  $(this).append("<p>...</p>");
 });

 $("p").bind('click', function(event){
  alert("...");
 })
});
```

Не работает событие привязанное к элементу, созданному первым событием. Что не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы пытались привязать событие к выборке элементов, делая выборку, когда самих элементов еще не существовало. Соответственно, поскольку привязывать событие было не к чему, оно ни к чему и не привязалось.

Иными словами, **элементы должны существовать на момент привязки события**.
Надо делать так:

```
$("div").on("click", "p", function(event){
  alert("...");
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Событие не существует в отрыве от элементов. Второй бинд осуществляется так: делается выборка элементов `p`, и на них вешается обработчик события. Все те элементы, которые в эту выборку не попали, обработчика иметь не будут. Однако, есть хак с делегирвоаним событий от вышестоящих элементов, он реализован в jQuery методом `.on()`.

Answer (score 3):

Читаем [документацию](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

> Handlers are attached to the **currently selected** elements in the jQuery
> object, so those elements **must exist at the point the call to `.bind()` occurs**.
> For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().

`bind()` привязывает обработчик к уже существующим элементам. Если хотите, чтобы он распространялся на элементы, которые на момент привязки не существуют, используйте [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).